# Deploy php web application on Elastic Beanstalk using Jenkins, git and eb cli

Tags: php, jenkins, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli, ebcli

I have a php application that i want to deploy to an elastic beanstalk environment using Jenkins. The Code is on git and i want to be able to use eb cli commands like
eb use 
eb deploy.

So, i am not sure how to make this work... as in how to set up the credentials so that i can have the eb cli commands run using the Jenkins shell.

Any thoughts about how to go about this would be very helpful.

My script currently looks a bit like this

```
git fetch

git checkout "$GIT_REF"

git pull origin "$GIT_REF"

eb use "$CUSTOM_EB_ENV"

eb deploy
```

$GIT_REF and $CUSTOM_EB_ENV are variables pointing to git branch and ElasticBeanstalk environment name.

When I run the job, i get the following error

```
+ git fetch
+ git checkout master
Previous HEAD position was 36f0456t... f
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
+ git pull origin master
From github.com:something/foo_bar
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
+ eb use Environment_name
ERROR: Operation Denied. The security token included in the request is invalid.
+ eb deploy
ERROR: This branch does not have a default environment. You must either specify an environment by typing "deploy my-env-name" or set a default environment by typing "eb use my-env-name".
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the EB CLI in a directory you first have to run `eb init` but it looks like you have already done that.

The problem you are having seems to be from the lack of valid credentials. The EB CLI pulls credentials the same way the AWS CLI does, you can find more information in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#config-settings-and-precedence).

You will most likely have to setup a pair of AWS credentials for your jenkins server. One way to do this would be to created the file `$JENKINS_HOME/.aws/credentials` and store your AWS credentials in there.

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = MYAWSACCESSKEY
aws_secret_access_key = MYAWSSECRETKEY
```

With that file created the EB CLI will automatically pull the credentials and run the desired operations.